# Material UI Text Field, Current Cursor Position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, material-ui

How can I get the current cursor (caret) position in a materialUI text field?

https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/

Basically, I have a need to modify the string contents at a particular index (for example, insert a char X between char #3 and char #4).

I understand that using the `onChange`, `onClick` and `onFocus` events will flag that a position change may have taken taken place (ie click mouse, or, say move using left/right arrow buttons, or type something), but then if I have a reference to the text-field object, which method or property would then permit me to determine where the caret is exactly positioned (index value `0 .. n-1`)?

In `jQuery`, I think this can be obtained via the `selectionStart` property, so how exactly is the best way for a MaterialUI textfield?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [inputRef prop](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props) to get a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) to the `input` DOM element. That ref can then be used to get the `selectionStart` property of the DOM element.

Working example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function App() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const [selectionStart, setSelectionStart] = React.useState();
  const updateSelectionStart = () =>
    setSelectionStart(inputRef.current.selectionStart);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        onSelect={updateSelectionStart}
        inputRef={inputRef}
        defaultValue="Initial Text"
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      selectionStart: {selectionStart}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]